# Open a local document copy from word web addins

Tags: ms-word, office-addins

I am developing a word web addin in which I want to download documents from the server. The download part is done I need help in how to open a downloaded file in another instance with the help of the task pane that is already open in the first document.
Is there any way to do this? can I get any tutorial for this? I searched for the documentation but didn't find any.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Office web add-ins (using `OfficeJS`) work under the context of currently opened document in Word (a single document). You can't use and add-in to download another Word document and open it. This is a potential breach hole.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .